# Объект в условии GROUP BY в C# LINQ - некорректная группировка, если использовать не анонимный тип

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Есть тестовый список пользователей:

```
public class ClassForOrderBy
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public int Priority { get;set; }
    public long OwnerId { get;set; }
        
    public ClassForOrderBy(string name, int priority, int ownerId)
    {
        Name = name;
        Priority = priority;
        OwnerId = ownerId;
    }
}

List<ClassForOrderBy> t = new List<ClassForOrderBy>()
{
    new ClassForOrderBy("Иван",14,5),
    new ClassForOrderBy("Маша",27,6),
    new ClassForOrderBy("Маша",97,7),
    new ClassForOrderBy("Иван",60,8)
};
```

Так же есть тип для группировки (далее в этом типе будут добавляться свойства и заполняться по определенному условию, т.е. объект группировки будет меняться, остальные свойства будут null):

```
private class AdvancedGroupByFilter
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public AdvancedGroupByFilter(string name) => Name = name;
}
```

Необходимо сгруппировать элементы списка по свойству "Name". Для группировки я использую метод расширения LINQ (GroupBy), но он странно себя ведет:

- если указать анонимный тип `t.GroupBy(x => new {x.Name})`, то мы получаем на выходе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- если указать тип BaseGroupByFilter `t.GroupBy(x => new BaseGroupByFilter(x.Name))`, то мы получаем на выходе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Анонимные типы мне не подходят, так как далее будут дополнительные условие OrderBy и ThenBy, которые должны знать, объект какого типа использовался в GroupBy.
Почему группировка так странно себя ведет и как заставить ее отрабатывать правильно при указании не анонимного типа?

Comment: В вашем классе для группировки вы забыли реализовать методы equals и hashcode

Comment: Из-за этого работает некорректно? А как тогда это реализуется в анонимном типе?

Comment: В анонимном типе это реализуется автоматически, с участием всех свойств. Что именно там будет написано я хз, но вы можете это выяснить если поковыряете документацию или декомпилируете свою сборку с анонимным типом.

Comment: tym32167, Вы совершенно правы. Так все работает корректно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Публикую ответ на свой вопрос (возможно, кому-нибудь пригодится).

В комментарии к вопросу **tym32167** был прав, когда рекомендовал переопределить методы Equals и GetHashCode.
В результате имеем нечто следующее (дополнительно, для наглядности, добавил в тип BaseGroupByFilter свойство OwnerId с типом nullable long):

```
private class BaseGroupByFilter
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public long? OwnerId { get; }
    
    public BaseGroupByFilter(string name, long? ownerId = null)
    {
        Name = name;
        OwnerId = ownerId;
    }
    
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as BaseGroupByFilter);

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hash = (OwnerId != null ? OwnerId.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hash = (hash * 27) ^ Name.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }

    private bool Equals(BaseGroupByFilter other) => 
        other != null && other.Name == this.Name && other.OwnerId == this.OwnerId;
}
```

Группировка теперь работает корректно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]